# Search LaTeX documentation with Alfred

Tags: pdf, spotlight, latex, alfred

I'm using Alfred v2 on Mavericks. I would like to use it to quickly locate documentation of LaTeX packages (PDF files). I have TeXLive 2014 installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2014`. I added `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/latex` to Alfred's search scope, but I'm not having any success. I tried searching using `open` and the backtick (file search) to no avail. I tried rebuilding the OSX metadata, but not joy there either. The `locate` command-line utility quickly finds the files in question, e.g.:

```
$ locate thmtools.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/latex/thmtools/thmtools.pdf
```

I should add that Spotlight can't find the files either. Is it a matter of permissions?

```
$ ll /usr/local/texlive/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel   680B Sep 21 11:51 2014
```

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

(1) Ready Alfred to accept a terminal command. Per [this support document](http://support.alfredapp.com/features:terminal), the standard method is to type `>` and then the terminal command. Similarly, in LaunchBar the action is built into the basic index, too, and one can initiate it with `term` or similar.

(2) Type `texdoc PackageName` where PackageName is the LaTeX package you're looking for the documentation for. For example: `texdoc enumitem` or `texdoc thmtools`.

It'll open the documentation PDF. That's it!

Note that of course you can also do this from the command line directly if you open a terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Powerpack user, I'd suggest creating a file filter. Follow the steps in the tutorial below, but drag in a LaTeX file instead to tell your filter which file types to include. You can include as many file types as you need.

http://blog.alfredapp.com/2014/04/24/tutorial-creating-an-alfred-workflow-without-a-single-line-of-code/

If you're not a Powerpack user, you can add the LaTeX file types to Alfred's Default Results. Go to the Preferences > Features > Default Results, click on "Advanced" and drag in your file types. However, be aware that this could clutter up your results quite a bit if you have a lot of files of this type, making it harder to locate your apps or essential files. :)